# LWC1041: Static id values are not allowed in iterators. Id values must be unique within a template and must be computed with an expression

Tags: lightning-web-components, html-area-component

I'm getting LWC1041 error in below html code in LWC.

```
<template for:each={page.sections} for:item="section" for:index="secIndx">
      <template if:true={value}>
          <div key={section} id=P+{section.pValue}+_S+{section.sValue}>
          </div>
     </template>
</template>
```

I'm trying to create the ID dynamically here, but still getting the error. Please let me know how can I correct it

Answer (score 1):

You can't use expressions like you would in Aura. You would need to calculate a value in your data and use that:

```
<div key={section.guid} id={section.guid}>
```

Which would be calculated somehow:

```
this.page.sections = this.page.sections.map(
  section => ({ 
    ...section, 
    guid: `P${section.pValue}_S${section.sValue}` 
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do I put this code in JS? In `connectedCallback()` or In any other method?

Comment: @SunilCN Depends on how you're using it. For wired data, use a custom wire handler and do it then, for static data, you can do it in connectedCallback or whatever.